# Premium theme - hardcoded url?

Tags: themes

I bought theme (White rock), installed new site **en.mysite.net** from scratch, but theme still references to **mysite.net**

Is there any chance that there is somewhere in theme files hardcoded url for which I bought theme, or something like that?

Or any other idea?

I installed new site to proper directory, url is proper - **en.mysite.net**.

Comment: check the Home URL and WordPress URL in General Settings.

Comment: Please switch to a core-bundled Theme, such as Twenty Fourteen or Twenty Thirteen, and verify whether or not your commercial Theme has any bearing on the issue.